# Checking To see if string is NOT equal to another string

Tags: ios, objective-c

Attempting to check if a "textfield" does not have "AM" or "PM" typed in either or, and if not do not let the user submit data to a database.

I figure something as simple as this should work, but appears not too in fact I get the `NSLog` every single time I type in "AM" or "PM" in either field, yet the  first `NSLog` shows "AM" or "PM" just fine. Not sure what the issue is.

Code:

```
if(![self.suffix.text isEqualToString:@"AM"] || ![self.suffix.text isEqualToString:@"PM"] || ![self.suffix2.text isEqualToString:@"AM"] || ![self.suffix2.text isEqualToString:@"PM"] )
    {
        NSLog(@"S: %@, E: %@", self.suffix.text, self.suffix2.text);
        NSLog(@"Invalid time suffixes!");

    }
else
{
 // submit data
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code says

```
if 
   (the suffix is not "AM")
   OR
   (the suffix is not "PM")
```

The suffix can't be both things at once, so it if is AM, it can't be PM also.

You want

```
if 
   (the suffix is not "AM")
   AND
   (the suffix is not "PM")
```

I leave it to you to change the code.

Comment: Got it and changed it to how I wanted it to work thanks for the tip would of gave it to you hadn't some other gentleman responded first!

Answer (score 1):

You want the form `!(s==AM || s==PM)` that's `s!=AM && s!=PM` using DeMorgan's.   Your || should be &&

Comment: Great got it thanks! In 3 minutes (when it lets me) I will accept your answer!

Answer (score 1):

It will print your log line if the value is not @"AM".  It will also print if it's not @"PM".  Since it can't be both at the same time, it will always print.

Answer (score 0):

The login seems to be incorrect.

Lets say user Types 'DM',

![self.suffix.text isEqualToString:@"AM"]  evaluates to [@"DM" isEqualToString:@"AM"] which is false. A not of that is true. For OR operation one true is true.

So, it has to be

```
 if(!([self.suffix.text isEqualToString:@"AM"] || [self.suffix.text isEqualToString:@"PM"] )&&
   !([self.suffix2.text isEqualToString:@"AM"] || [self.suffix2.text isEqualToString:@"PM"] ))
{
    NSLog(@"S: %@, E: %@", self.suffix.text, self.suffix2.text);
    NSLog(@"Invalid time suffixes!");

}
else
{
    // submit data
}
```